# @user = User.new(params[:user]) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`when I enter all the details in view form , while submitting the form I am getting this error.

This is my controller:
*controller/user_new_controller.rb*

```
class UserNewController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def create_user

        @user = User.new(params[:user])


        # @user.update_attributes(params[:user], permit[:user_attribute]
        if @user.save
            flash[:notice] = "You signed up successfully"
            flash[:color] = "valid"

        else
            flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
            flash[:color] = "invalid"
        end
        render "new"

    end
    def applicationview

    end

    private
    def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password)
    end
end
```

And This is my model:
    *models/user.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    before_save :encrypt_password
    after_save :clear_password

    def encrypt_password
        if password.present?
            salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
            encrypted_password = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, salt)
        end
    end

    def clear_password
        self.password = nil
    end

    attr_accessor :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
    # attr_accessor :user_attribute, :as => admin
    # attr_accessor :password
    # EMAIL_REGEX = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i
    # email_regexp = /^([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})$/i
    validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
    validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true 
        validates :password, :confirmation => true 
    validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create
end
```

And this is my view: 
   *views/applicationview.html.erb*

```
    <% @page_title = "UserAuth | Signup" %>

<div class = "Sign_Form">
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    <%= form_for(:user, :url => {:controller => 'user_new', :action => 'create_user'}) do |f| %>
    <p> Username </br> <%= f.text_field :username%> </p>
    <p> Email </br> <%= f.text_field :email%> </p>
    <p> Password </br><%= f.text_field :Password %> </p>
    <p> Password_confirmation </br> <%= f.text_field :Password_confirmation%> </p>
    <%= f.submit :Signup %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

And I am getting the below error shown in the image
I am getting ActiveModel error.

I am actually getting the details which i enter in view form, while I render it I am getting the answer below,

`{
"username": "jack", "email": "jack@yahoo.com" }`

I cant get my password and these values are not stored in my Database. In my log I am getting Unpermitted parameters: Password, Password_confirmation this action is happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
```

To:

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
```

This is because of [Strong Parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters)

Comment: Hey, Thanks now I am getting the params but the details are not stored in database I migrated my DB. What will be the solution ?

Comment: @Ami, Please add your question here above, "on your original question" then I'll update my answer. BTW, please check the answer if it is right. Thanks!